# Magento 2.1 Layered Navigation Category filter

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

Category filter is not displaying on layered navigation if cache is enabled. If i disable cache from backend it display category filter.

***How to solve such issue ?***

Any suggestion highly appreciated.